# Cannot access private members of same type in Java

Tags: java

I am unable to access private members of same type in Java.
I am creating a method 'add' on the Fraction type but I cannot access the other fractions private vars to compare.

```
public Fraction add(Fraction f) {
    int add1 = (this.numerator*f.denominator)+(this.denominator*f.numerator);
    int add2 = this.denominator*f.denominator;
    return createFraction(add1,add2);
}
```

Should I be using some sort of reflection feature to achieve this?

Extra info: I have not declared the private members on the interface.

Extra info: I am not permitted to use getters and setters on this class

Extra info: I am not permitted to make those fields public

Comment: “I have not declared the private members on the interface.” —What interface are you talking about?

Comment: "I am unable to access private members of same type in Java" accessibility doesn't depend on type of variable/field but on location where it was declared. "I have not declared the private members on the interface" if by interface you mean `Fraction` type then if those members are not declared in it you can't access them directly if they are private. Maybe consider adding some getters to access current *value* of those private variables.

Comment: Consider adding more context like how your classes actually look like (at least ones which contains private members you want to access and ones *from* which you want to access them).

Answer (score 2):

You should create getters and setters on your `Fraction` class so you can get the values of the private variables as well as set them.

```
public class Fraction{
   private int numerator;
   private int denominator;
   public Fraction(final int numerator, final int denominator){
     this.numerator = numerator;
     this.denominator = denominator;
   }
   public int getNumerator(){
     return this.numerator;
   }
   public int getDenominator(){
     return this.denominator;
   }
   public void setNumerator(final int numerator){
    this.numerator = numerator;
   }
   public void setDenominator(final int denominator){
    this.denominator = denominator;
   }
}
```

You can then change your code to this:

```
public Fraction add(Fraction f) {
    int add1 = (this.numerator*f.getDenominator())+(this.denominator*f.getNumerator());
    int add2 = this.denominator*f.getDenominator();
    return createFraction(add1,add2); //createFraction can be simply new Fraction(add1, add2);
}
```

You could use Reflection to get the value of the field by using `Field.setAccessible`, but it is much easier and cleaner to write a getter for the field.

Example Usage:

```
Field field = f.getClass().getDeclaredField("numerator"); 
f.setAccessible(true);
int numerator = (int) field.get(f);
```

Your code could then be changed to:

```
public Fraction add(Fraction f) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{
    Field fieldNumerator = f.getClass().getDeclaredField("numerator");
    fieldNumerator.setAccessible(true);
    Field fieldDenominator = f.getClass().getDeclaredField("denominator");
    fieldDenominator.setAccessible(true);
    final int numerator = (int) fieldNumerator.get(f);
    final int denominator = (int) fieldDenominator.get(f);
    int add1 = (this.numerator*denominator)+(this.denominator*numerator);
    int add2 = this.denominator*denominator;
    return createFraction(add1,add2); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment -I am not allowed to use getters and setters on this class

Comment: @user1688726 Then why don't you use public fields?

Comment: I am not allowed to make the fields public

Comment: @user1688726 I have edited my answer to add a method using reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your example - it says Unknown class 'f' - Fraction is the interface to class FractionImpl

Comment: Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @user1688726 I have edited my answer - see if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for that - it gets a NoSuchFieldException, although they are declared as     private int numerator  and private int denominator, I guess it may be something to do with it implementing an interface

Comment: You should cast this and f to FractionImpl before you can get access to its fields. Like this: ((FractionImpl) f).numerator. And check that it's really FractionImpl before with `instanceof`.

Comment: @a.yekimov Thank you so much that is working correctly now